# Implementation queue over Map.Entry<K, V>

Tags: java, dictionary, queue

I'm doing my homework. I need a `<key, value>` data structure to store the cache. Also I need my structure delete the oldest item when there is no space for the new element (analog of `LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry()`).

I want to implement a queue over `Map.Entry<K, V>` for the assignment. Is it right way to solve the problem?

Explanation:

```
public class Queue<K, V>
{
    protected LinkedList<MyEntry<K, V>> list;

    public Queue() {
        list = new LinkedList<MyEntry<K,V>>();
    }
    ////
}

final class MyEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private V value;

    public MyEntry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V value) {
        V old = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return old;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Queue<String, String> queue = new Queue<String>();
```

Comment: Please explain the task more precisely. What is the prupose of the queue to be implemented? Where is your variable to store the limit of elements? What about the cache?

Comment: @user905686, The purpose of the queue is a simple removal of the old item. THe variable to store the limit of elements exists in the class Queue. Cache is an abstraction for setting task.

Comment: I think you could start by reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html and take a look at this http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_EMDb5HG8zU/UIcuKYhNrZI/AAAAAAAABPA/-aJ4t-OX6NY/s1600/page-caching-linkedhashmap.png. Then you probably know how to code it yourself. It would really take some time for me so I'll just skip coding it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use LinkedHashMap than the first element in the map that you move with the iterator since LinkedHashMap keep the order of the pairs in the same order that you enter them.  notice that if you fetch object from the map you need to remove and add it again to keep the order of the pairs in the linkedHashMap